# In a one to one or one to many relationship in a database, which table must have the foreign key?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, relational-database, erd

Sorry If my question seems too obvious but I still can't find the logic between a relationship of a database model.

ONE TO ONE:

If I have a customer that has **only one**  address where do I have to put my foreign key ?

I first thought it would be a good idea to put it on the customer's table; one column with a foreign key referring to an id of an address.

Because if I need to create a customer, first I would need to create an address.

[image: custfk]

But I have found some example on the internet
, where they put a foreign key in the address' table, referring to an id of a customer

[image: addressfk]

ONE TO MANY :

And the same question would apply if a customer **can have multiple addresses**, in which table, should I put my foreign key ?

Comment: The first [_One on One_] is more a style (_depending of the requirements ofcourse_) the second you need to see who owns who

Comment: what do you mean with own ? I mean a customer has an address...

Comment: Let's put an example you have 3 houses, the houses owns you or you own the houses? Depending on of your answer then the parent id go in the place of the children.

Comment: mmm, ok got your idea, thanks man

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The foreign key goes on the "many" side.

For example, if a `sales_order` is associated with at most one `customer`, and a `customer` can have zero, one or more `sales_order`

Then we put `customer_id` in the `sales_order` table, as a reference to the (unique) `id` column in `customer` table.

This means that we will first need to add a row to `customer` before we can add a `sales_order` for that `customer`. (The foreign key constraint will prevent us from adding a row in `sales_order` that has a value in `customer_id` column that doesn't exist in `id` column of `customer`.

--

For the special case of a one-to-one relationship, we can implement that the same way as a one-to-many, with an additional UNIQUE constraint on the foreign key column. It really comes down to deciding which direction of the relationship is mandatory, and which is optional. Basically, which table will we add a row to first? The table where we add rows later will have the foreign key constraint referencing the table that we previously added a row...

Comment: It could be added that in the especial case of him, the address could come all thogether with the clients, at least we're not keeping a history of address of course